# "Not to me, I wasn't married to her!" in Memento (1999)

Tags: connotations

In Memento, there is a scene where Lenny and Natalie argue with each other.

> N: Kill him. I'll pay you.
> L: What do you think I am? I'm not gonna kill someone for money.
> N: What, then? Love? What would you kill for? You'd kill for your wife, wouldn't you?
> L: That's different.
> N: Not to me, I wasn't married to her!
> L: Hey, don't talk about my wife.

I can understand these lines word by word, but I'm not sure what Natalie intended to suggest by saying **I wasn't married to her!**.

Comment: The gist is that Natalie is indifferent to Lenny's reasons for killing -- whether it's for money or love -- and she just wants him to kill someone because she knows he is capable of doing it. I don't see a logical connection between the words, "I wasn't married to her!" and her intent, but she's not speaking rationally, so it doesn't make literal sense. Think of it as a more interesting line of dialogue than, "I don't care!"

Answer (score 1):

I see no special meaning here.  I assume you understand the basic meaning of "be married to someone".  And the grammatical construction "I wasn't X".

Natalie is just making the point that if Lenny would kill someone "for his wife" (I suppose this means that he would kill someone if his wife asked for it), then he should be willing to kill someone if she asks for it. Lenny's point that "his wife is special for Lenny" is irrelevant to Natalie, because Natalie wasn't married to her.

Perhaps you know something more about the character of Lenny, Natalie and Lenny's wife that would make this make sense.